# cannot import name '_has_surrogates' from partially initialized module 'email.utils'

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.8, odoo-13

I tried to use odoo 13 and i worked with python 3.8 , but this error python always appears

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_has_surrogates' from partially initialized module 'email.utils' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Python38\lib\email\utils.py)
```

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're using a file name which is creating a circular dependency with the one being used in 'email.utils'.

**Rename your file name.**

It shouldn't be too generic like email.py, calendar.py, etc.

e.g. if you're using `email.py` as your working python file, rename it to `project_mailer.py` or whatever suits better. As long as your selected name is not creating any circular dependency, you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the entire log or a better explanation of the problem circular import is just one of the possible cases.

One solution is to update email package to the newest version

If you problem is with ODOO and `pycharm` you probably have to uncheck add content roots to `PYTHONPATH` and add source roots to `PYTHONPATH` on run configurations.

Answer (score 0):

If someone come across this in the future and is particularly working with ODOO, simply make sure that you marked the ENTERPRISE and/or ODOO-SERVER as the source roots instead of their ADDONS folders.

Alternatively, on the run configurations, click on modify options and uncheck the ones related to python path (image below). A clean installation with `pip install -r requirements.txt` is usually good in a virtual environment, but the definition of source/root folders stole about 2 hours of my life, so... I hope you arrive here quickly!

Also, since you are here, activate the "Emulate console" variable in the modifications, it is neat.

[Pycharm configurations print screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIQjT.png)